# Rust Nom How to use ? in parsers

Tags: rust, nom

It's the first time I have used a parser combinator, so maybe I just have a misunderstanding about how I should use a parser combinator.

I have the following code which works in general:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd53125d3ed874b5e70f3aaae32e2e94

The problem is, I don't understand how I can get rid of the `.unwrap()` in my parse_method and parse_url functions and use the `?` operator instead. I have already read https://github.com/rust-bakery/nom/blob/main/doc/error_management.md but absolutely don't understand how to apply it in this case.

I think I have to create a custom Error Enum and implement the ParseError trait. I tried that, but without any success. Unfortunately, the nom crate does not have many examples, and the ones that are there never use the `?` operator.

This leads me to think that I misunderstood how I should use a parser combinator. Is the idea that I just parse the parts and assemble the parts later where I do not return IResult or is the idea that I should use `.map_err` and return noms own error types? I am really lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please put the code for a [mre] in the question itself. [A link to an external repository is not enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/5397009).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`map_res`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/combinator/fn.map_res.html) combinator:

```rust
fn parse_method(input: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], Method> {
    let (input, method) = map_res(
        terminated(take_till(is_space), multispace0),
        Method::from_bytes,
    )(input)?;

    Ok((input, method))
}
```

In general, you should prefer using combinators over manually successively calling parsers: [full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4370d8d28b40efb71c27285e3aea6b2b)